# First order logic: if A sentence is satisfiable then it is satisfiable in the natural number + even function

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, model-theory, natural-numbers, satisfiability

Let $\Sigma=\{R(,),f(),g(,)\}$ and let f,and g be functions, and R a relation in FOL logic without equallity.

Prove or disprove:

1. if $\phi$ is satisfiable and a universal sentence, then there is a model N where its domain is the natural numbers, and f is a function which its image is the even natural numbers.
2. if $\phi$ is satisfiable and a sentence, then there is a model N where its domain is the natural numbers, and f is a function which its image is the even natural numbers.

I believe that the first one is true, because we can convert it to a herbrand model, and then replace each with an even number, then add to the domain the odd natural numbers.

The second seems to be a false statement, But I look for such sentence. Probably it is related somehow that an $\aleph_{0}$ elements are missing

Edit:
g is a binary function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have almost no experience with FOL without equality, so I may be mistaken, but I believe both are true. In fact, any countable consistent theory has such a model. I assume that your $f,g$ are unary and $R$ is binary, but if they have different arities, the same solution should still work, with obvious modifications.

It suffices to find a countable model such that the range of $f$ is infinite and co-infinite.

By Lowenheim-Skolem, fix any countable (possibly finite) model $M$ and any $x_0\in M$ and $y_0:= f^M(x_0)$. Choose sequences $(x_n)_{n\in \mathbf N}, (y_n)_{n\in \mathbf N}$ such that $x_n,y_n$ are distinct and $x_n,y_n\notin M$ for $n>0$. Let $M'=M\cup \{x_n,y_n\mid n\in \mathbf N\}$.

Define $M'$ as en extension of $M$ in the following way: $f^{M'}(x_n)=y_n$, $g^{M'}(x_n)=g^M(x_0)$, $f^{M'}(y_n)=f^M(y_0)$, $g^{M'}(y_n)=g^M(y_0)$, $R^{M'}(x_n,x_m)=R^M(x_0,x_0)$, $R^{M'}(x_n,y_m)=R^M(x_0,y_0)$, $R^{M'}(x_n,z)=R^M(x_0,z)$ etc.

Then $M\equiv M'$ by an Ehrenfeucht-Fraisse argument: the duplicator can choose $x_0$ in response to any $x_n$ (including $x_0$), $y_0$ in response to any $y_n$, and $z$ in response to any $z\in M$.

$M'$ is then the desired model, since $\{y_n\mid n\in \mathbf N\}$ is contained in the range of $f^{M'}$, while $\{x_n\mid n>0\}$ is contained in its complement.

Comment: nice argument! gosh, this question makes me realize how little intuition for FOL without equality I have

Comment: Actually g is binary as mentioned in the question.

Comment: @thecorrectanswer: well, you added that after I wrote my answer! anyway, as I wrote, it doesn't really matter, the definition of $g^{M'}$ should hopefully be clear anyway. Or isn't it?

Comment: @AtticusStonestrom: thanks. I had no intuition myself, but I was thinking of counterexamples and realised there seems to be no reason for what I wrote above not to work.